# Angular + ui-select initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to figure out why, in this plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/FeseWk77UQNzZwO0e7D7?p=preview),
the first ui-select is not correctly initialized like the second one.
The initialization is pretty simple:

```
$scope.obj = {
  "id": "6101",
  niveau: [{
    "id": "3",
    "nom": "Bac+1"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "nom": "Bac+3"
  }],
  niveau2: [
   $scope.liste[2],$scope.liste[4]],

};
```

it works well with `ng-model="niveau2"` but not with `ng-model="niveau"`.

If anyone can enlighten me here, thx

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first ui-select, the objects may have the same properties as what is in the `liste` array, but they aren't the **same** *objects* as what is in the `liste` array.

Basically, this expression will be false, and that is why it doesn't show up (because they are not in the `liste` array).

```
$scope.obj.niveau[0] === $scope.obj.niveau2[0];
```

Or another way to think of it is that the objects inside the `niveau` array are NOT in the `liste` array, even though they have the same properties, e.g. the following expression is true

```
$scope.obj.niveau[0] !== $scope.liste[2];
```